# Removing a user from channel using telegram methods

Tags: node.js, telegram

I am trying to remove a user from the channel using Node.js and telegram core methods. this is my code:

```js
await api.call('channels.editBanned', {
  channel: {
    _: 'inputChannel',
    channel_id,
    access_hash: channel.access_hash
  },
  participant: {
    _: 'inputPeerUser',
    user_id: user.id,
    access_hash: user.access_hash
  },
  banned_rights: {
    _: 'chatBannedRights',
    view_messages: false,
    send_messages: false,
    send_media: false,
    send_stickers: false,
    send_gifs: false,
    send_games: false,
    send_inline: false,
    embed_links: false,
    until_date: null,
  },
});
```

I am sure that the user and channel ID and access hash are fine, and as a response, I get my channel data but the `updates` array is empty and this is not working. Any help, please?